# Zend Framework 2: setAttribute() on a non-object error occurs when trying to edit

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new to the PHP Zend Framework 2 and I'm going through one of the online tutorials in learning how to use it.  The tutorial involves having you create and edit albums.  The problem is when I try to edit an album by clicking on the **edit** links, I get an error stating:

*Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object*

**Controller:**

```
public function editAction()
 {
     $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
     if (!$id) {
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
             'action' => 'add'
         ));
     }

     // Get the Album with the specified id.  An exception is thrown
     // if it cannot be found, in which case go to the index page.
     try {
         $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);
     }
     catch (\Exception $ex) {
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
             'action' => 'index'
         ));
     }

     $form = new AlbumForm();
     $form->bind($album);
     $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {
         $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
         $form->setData($request->getPost());

         if ($form->isValid()) {
             $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);

             // Redirect to list of albums
             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
         }
    // EDIT: This bracket below was missing originally
    // This is what was causing the 'setAttribute' error when
    // Clicking on the edit links for any of my albums
     }

     return array(
         'id' => $id,
         'form' => $form,
     );
 }
```

**View:**

```
<?php
//module/Album/view/album/album/edit.phtml:

$title = 'Edit album';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>

<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?> </h1>

<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
'album',
array(
    'action' => 'edit',
    'id'     => $this->id,
    )
));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();

?>
```

EDIT: Here is the code from *AlbumForm.php*

**AlbumForm.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Album\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class AlbumForm extends Form
{
   public function __construct($name = null)
   {
    // we want to ignore the name passed
    parent::__construct('album');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'Hidden',
        ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Title',
        ),
        ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'artist',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Artist',
            ),
        ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'Go',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
   }
}

?>
```

I'm not really sure why this occurring since I'm following the tutorial exactly, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show us the AlbumForm class?

Comment: @Iku See my edit above, I added 'AlbumForm.php'

Comment: Could you also provide a longer stack trace, or more specifically, what file the error is occurring in?

Comment: @Svengali Ok, when you go to the url 'localhost/album' which lists all of the albums, when you click on any of the 'edit' links, this is when the error occurs.  The actual error is: ' Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in C:\Zend\projects\skeleton\module\Album\view\album\album\edit.phtml on line 12 '

Comment: in your view file remove line with `$form = $this->form;` you already have it as `$form` variable from controller

Comment: @Alex I tried removing '$form = $this->form;' but then I get an undefined variable error.

Comment: The problem is that the `$form` variable isn't getting to your view. So are you certain that it's `editAction()` that's being called?

Comment: do you have `add` action done already?

Comment: Hey guys, I actually figured out what the problem was after all.  It was within the 'AlbumController.php' file where I was missing a bracket '{' to close up the 'editAction' class properly.  My application can now edit fine.  I'm going to make an edit to my code above.  Thank you for all of your help.